# Pretest scores differ amongst groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, repeated-measures

In my analysis I compare 3 treatment groups with a pre- and posttest (emotionality scores 0 - 100), so I want to use the repeated measures. Unfortunately, the pretest scores differ significantly amoungst groups which makes me think that simply running the test would not be valid. When I transfer the scores to relative ones, I get uninterpretable data due to the method of measurement (0 = not emotional, 100 = very emotional): a baseline score of 40 and postscore of 80 should not be interpreted as equal to a baseline score of 2 and a postscore of 4.

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Was this a randomized experiment? If no, e.g. stratifying the analysis by propensity score may be an option.

Comment: It was a randomized experiment indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best method is a multilevel model, with person as a random effect and a random intercept.  While ordinary regression has this model:

$Y = X \beta + \epsilon $

a multilevel model is:

$Y = X \beta + Z \gamma + \epsilon$

These models have been extensively discussed here and in many other places.

Comment: Thank you for your input. With multilevel model I assume you mean that I should use a mixed factor analysis? Because that was what I meant by repeated measures, I use SPSS and add Condition as Between-Subjects Factor, my bad. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit more as in how to run the analysis? I'm sorry to ask but  am quite new to statistics.

Comment: I have no idea what a mixed factor analysis is and I don't use SPSS. But I will elaborate in my answer.